# On a local machine: How can I download and save a file using Javascript and ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, activex, download, adodb

This is a binary file. I would like to download and save a file with Javascript. This is all happening on a local machine. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean silent save without user interaction? If yes, I'm afraid there will be no reliable way due to security reasons. Otherwise, you can use some ActiveX download component.